# SQL JOIN on both

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following SQL which creates a friends list with other info:

```
SELECT DISTINCT exchange.id userid, exchange.name username, exchange.lastactivity     lastactivity, exchange.id avatar, exchange.id link, cometchat_status.message, cometchat_status.status
FROM buddy
JOIN exchange ON buddy.penpalA = exchange.id
LEFT JOIN cometchat_status ON exchange.id = cometchat_status.userid
WHERE buddy.penpalB =887
ORDER BY username ASC
```

It works fine for displaying a list of someones friends where the current member is penpalA, however I want to make it so that it also checks to see if penpalB is the current member and if so takes the info from that column and not the other one as either penpalA or penpalB could be the current member and it currently isnt checking this.

How can i modify it so it works?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is rarely necessary and usually indicative of a mistake. Show us what kind of output you get if you remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any field which is set to some value which defines whether something is set to current or not??For e.g suppose you have one of the field in the database table named "current" the value can be 0 or 1 only.0 if its not current and 1 if its current.
Now in the query you can add WHERE current='1' and based on that extract the corresponding fields you want from the database.

Comment: by current user, i mean the user who is currently logged in for example $_SESSION['user'] = 887

Comment: you can use the same procedure to check whether someone is logged on or not.it can be used in many cases for e.g. to check whether user is registered member,whether user has activated account etc

Comment: i dont want to check if the user is logged in or not, i dont think you understand; i want the sql to check penpalA AND penpalB to see if its the user